# Unable to align the text with toggle button

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<label>Some Text</label>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use table-cell and vertical align (see the following code snippet).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.slider-label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding-right: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<label class="slider-label">Some Text</label>
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" checked>
   <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
</body>
</html>
```